# php session multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, session, multidimensional-array

```
$_SESSION['items_' . $restaurant_id]["menu_0"] = array(
    order_id" => $order_id,
    'user_order_id' => $last_order["user_order_id"],
    "menu_id" => $menu_id,
    "qty" => $qty,
);
```

that code is my session and will be return become this :

```
["items_250"]=>
array(2) {
["menu_0"]=>
array(3) {
  ["user_order_id"]=>
  string(2) "85"
  ["menu_id"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "236"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "357"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "232"
  }
  ["qty"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
}
```

in my `$menu_id is array :

```
array(4) {
[0]=>
string(3) "236"
[1]=>
string(3) "357"
[3]=>
string(3) "232"
}
```

this is my `$qty` :

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

i want trying to make my session will be return like this :

```
["items_250"]=>
array(3) {
["menu_0"]=>
array(3) {
  ["user_order_id"]=>
  string(2) "85"
  ["menu_id"]=>
  string(3) "236"
  ["qty"]=>
  int(1)
}
["menu_1"]=>
array(3) {
  ["user_order_id"]=>
  string(2) "85"
  ["menu_id"]=>
  string(3) "357"
  ["qty"]=>
  int(1)
}
["menu_2"]=>
array(3) {
  ["user_order_id"]=>
  string(2) "85"
  ["menu_id"]=>
  string(3) "232"
  ["qty"]=>
  int(1)
}
```

guys can you help me how to make my session become like that?

thank you (:

Comment: just add another for loop inside it creating another dimension for that row

Comment: can you show me how to make it? @Ghost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use good ol' `for` loop. First get the `count`, then create the necessary rows:

```
$count = count($menu_id); // get count
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $_SESSION['items_' . $restaurant_id]['menu_' . $i] = array(
        'user_order_id' => $last_order['user_order_id'],
        'menu_id'       => $menu_id[$i],
        'qty'           => $qty[$i],
    );
}
```